# Already launched Activity is not displayed in front when launching Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

that's the second question concerning my custom Android launcher project.
This time, I encountered a problem opening Apps. It only occurs, when an App is already opened and therefore in the history.
E.g. if I open the Settings App and after that the Facebook App, both of them appear in the history. When I try launching the Settings App again, it just shows me the Facebook App.
Here is the source code of the Launching Intent. ActionName ist the PackageName of the ApplicationInfo.

```
           Intent launchIntent = activity.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(actionName);
        launchIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        //launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
          //      Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        activity.startActivity(launchIntent);
```

I tried all imaginable Flag-Configurations. Not just the ones you see in the code sample. (REORDER_TO_FRONT,...) Maybe I missed one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where you launch the Setting App from?

Comment: Every Application gets a container class with necessary information, such as icon, package name and the activity to start the Intent. That Activity is marked as action.MAIN, category.LAUNCHER, category.HOME, category.DEFAULT.

Comment: Is no one there who could help?